# std::vector::erase() erases the wrong element

Tags: c++, opencv, stl, std, stdvector

So I search for an element in a vector, I store it in an iterator and I call the `erase()` on it. Unfortunately, when I set the breakpoints and check what's happening, I see that even if the `closestObjectIt` points to the right element, that element still remains in the vector, some other element being deleted. I have no clue what is wrong here; why the right iterator is not deleted?

I also had in my project some implicit conversions from `std::vector` to `cv::vector` (from OpenCV) and vice-versa, but I eliminated them, being suspicious.

```
DetectedObject Head:: findTheClosestObjectFromObjects(std::vector<DetectedObject>& objects)
{
  float minDistance = 10000;
  std::vector<DetectedObject>::iterator closestObjectIt;
  DetectedObject closestObject = objects[0];

  for(std::vector<DetectedObject>::iterator it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it)
  {
    float distance = computeDistance2((*it));
    if (distance < minDistance)
    {
        minDistance = distance;
        closestObject = (*it);
        closestObjectIt = it;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Before erease: " << std::endl;
  objects.erase(closestObjectIt);
  std::cout << "After erease: " << std::endl;

  return closestObject;
}
```

Comment: Try objects.erase(object.begin() + closestObjectIt)

Comment: There is undefined behaviour if you call this with an empty vector, because of `objects[0]`. Other than that, it seems fine. Try actually generating some output to confirm suspicions; debugger info can be misleading or wrong. Preferably post a minimal but complete program that showd the problem occurring.

Comment: As you're not using a vector of pointers, it's worth checking `DetectedObject`'s copy-assignment operator.

Comment: Use `std::find_if` instead of that loop.

Comment: @donutmonger, it creates an error stating that there is no operator+ for such operands.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I would soon update the question with output, but I came to this problem because later it returns the same closestObject every time.

Comment: @MaximChetrusca that might indicate a problem with copying, as Matthew Finlay suggested - perhaps post the class definition including the body of the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator (if any)

Comment: @MaximChetrusca - You could also replace that entire loop with a single call to `std::min_element`.

Comment: Thanks to all guys, I found the problem in the assignment operator of DetectedObject class. I will accept @MatthewFinlay's answer as soon as I can (there should pass some time since the question was posted). 
Thanks for other suggestions as well!

Comment: Cheers, I've just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above looks good, have you tried looking at `DetectedObject`'s copy-assignment operator? When you erase an element, this is what's used (in c++03) to move the other elements in the vector, so an error here will stop `erase` operating properly.

Answer (score 2):

vector::erase(it) doesn't remove the element pointed by it. It calls to copy assignment of managed object to assign the element pointed by it with the next one. This step is done for the next one too, and continue until it reach the end element and it will really delete the memory of end element.
So, remember to write copy assignment operator for Class that will be managed in vector and will be used with erase() method. The second ways to overcome this issue is use std::vector of Pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class BarcodeTagging {
    int value_;
    public:
    BarcodeTagging(int value) : value_(value) {
    }

    ~BarcodeTagging() {
        std::cout << "Delete " << this << "\n";
    }

    const BarcodeTagging& operator=(const BarcodeTagging& other) {
        std::cout << "Call to this \n";
        std::cout << "who calling: " << this << "\n";
        std::cout << "who is called: " << &other << "\n";
        value_ = other.value_;
        return *this;
    }

    int GetValue() const {
        return value_;
    }

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector<BarcodeTagging> taggings;
    BarcodeTagging tag1(1);
    BarcodeTagging tag2(2);
    BarcodeTagging tag3(3);
    taggings.push_back(tag1);
    taggings.push_back(tag2);
    taggings.push_back(tag3);

    std::cout << "Before erase \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < taggings.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "element " << i << ": " << &(taggings[i]) << ", with value: " << 
        taggings[i].GetValue() << "\n";
    }
    taggings.erase(taggings.begin());
    std::cout << "After erase \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < taggings.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "element " << i << ": " << &(taggings[i]) << ", with value: " << 
        taggings[i].GetValue() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
Delete 0x55faf3c98c20
Delete 0x55faf3c98c40
Delete 0x55faf3c98c44
Before erase 
element 0: 0x55faf3c98c20, with value: 1
element 1: 0x55faf3c98c24, with value: 2
element 2: 0x55faf3c98c28, with value: 3
Call to this 
who calling: 0x55faf3c98c20
who is called: 0x55faf3c98c24
Call to this 
who calling: 0x55faf3c98c24
who is called: 0x55faf3c98c28
Delete 0x55faf3c98c28
After erase 
element 0: 0x55faf3c98c20, with value: 2
element 1: 0x55faf3c98c24, with value: 3
Delete 0x7ffe1d958b40
Delete 0x7ffe1d958b30
Delete 0x7ffe1d958b20
Delete 0x55faf3c98c20
Delete 0x55faf3c98c24
```